# Converting XAML to new build in TFS2015

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Have successfully created my TFS2012 XAML builds in TFS2015.
This is for a compiled ASP.NET web application and the XAML build output is the entire site folders, compiled DLL, support DLLs etc - the same result as if you do Publish by right-clicking on the project.

Thought I would have a look at how the new VSO build compared so used the Visual studio build template, passed the publishing profile as /P:... and created a drop folder.

The build runs "successfully" but produces no output.  The source is copied into the directory on the build machine but the logs show no evidence of the web.config transformation and does not seem to generate any artifacts for copying despite the build reporting "success"....I am sure I am missing something very basic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use "Visual Studio Build" step and as Arguments for MSBuild we use following line:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=$(DeploymentConfiguration)
```

On Variables tab page DeploymentConfiguration has to be configured. It must be the Name of the publish Profile (filename of the pubxml file). If the file Name is Build.pubxml the publish profile is "Build".

for example:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=Build
```

The transform XML task is defined in the .csproj file as follows:

```
  <Target Name="CustomWebConfigTransform">
      <TransformXml source="Web.config" transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" destination="Web.config" />
  </Target>
```

If you want to generate Artifacts please use the "Publish Build Artifacts" build step.

After a successful build you can see a link to the artifacts at the top of the overview of the build (next to Summary and Timeline).

Comment: Thanks Sebastian - I was missing that /p:DeployOnBuild=True parameter now everything behaves itself :-)  interesting that parameter is not required in the XAML builds.  Not wholly convinced this is actually a better build environment as it has taken a week of fiddling and wading through documents to get everything working at least satisfactorily.